# How to receive click events on a div covered by an empty cell of a html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

In a web page, I have several overlapping html tables (set by using css style `position:absolute`). In the cell of one of these tables, there is a div element defined, with a `click` event on it (using `jquery`).

Here is the problem : **if a div element is covered by an empty cell of another overlapping table, the div element wont receive click events anymore.** One of the conditions to make this happened is that the covered div have to be set in DOM structure before the covering table.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CjDZ/) for a better example. As you can see, red element dont receive click events anymore (because covered by the top empty cell of table containing blue element).

I know it sounds strange to have a page like this, but the reason is that in the real application these tables are `ui-draggable` (thus they can overlap), and the table structure is used to display small organizational charts).

Notes :

I cannot just exchange tables position in `DOM` or add a `z-index` on one of the tables to solve the issue, because as said earlier the tables are draggable (using `jquery-ui`) thus user can change the situation (blue can overlap red or red can overlap blue).

Comment: Here is a great solution to the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this with CSS, without modifying HTML, is to set `pointer-events:none;` to the overlapping table, and then `pointer-events: all;` to the specific TD that is blue.

See [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4CjDZ/2/)

Comment: Not supported by Opera or Internet Explorer but yes this is correct.

Comment: I confirm it works. I would have prefer a solution that works everywhere but that's acceptable. One other idea i had in mind was to catch click event from document mouseup event (that always occurs) and then check myself if that click occurs in one of the div's. if so, i would then fake a click event on div (using jquery trigger() method). anyway that solution sounds pretty complex and maybe wont work very well with jquery-ui.

Comment: Click the tick button then :)